React Native Android App Network Request Failed On Physical Device
I am new to react native and currently I am using a bare workflow react native without expo.
The scenario is
-Have a docker keycloak realm service set up to test some authentication to spit out a token when authenticated
-When running virtual device (virtual phone) using Android Studio, I am able to authenticate and get a token back from docker keycloak service. Also tested with Postman and I am also getting a token.
-When I generate an apk through ./gradlew assembleRelease in the android folder and install it on my device, I always receive error of "Network request failed"
-If I plug my phone and use it to debug the app while connected to PC, I still get Network request failed
-So, I am sending a request with HTTP instead of HTTPS and I made sure to go to AndroidManifest.xml and set
<application
...
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
-Before when I was using local 192.168.etc...:8080 It would just network request failed instantly. Now if I use 10.0.2.2, it waits around 7-10 seconds before I get Network request failed
Thank you for anybody's help. I have hit a brick wall here and I am not familiar with networking or connecting.
Here is the code segment for my loginHandler
//-------------------------------------------------------------
const loginHandler = async () => {
const url = `http://10.0.2.2:8080/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token`;
const body = `client_id=login-client&client_secret=SOME+RANDOM+CHARS&username=${encodeURIComponent(username)}&password=${encodeURIComponent(password)}&grant_type=password`;

const timeoutPromise = new Promise((_, reject) =>
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Request timed out')), 15000)
);

try {
  setMessage('');
  console.log('Perform login with:', username, password);
  console.log('URL FOR LOGGING:', url);
  console.log('BODY OF URL:', body);

  const fetchPromise = fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: body,
  });

  const response = await Promise.race([fetchPromise, timeoutPromise]);

  console.log('Response Status:', response.status);

  if (!response.ok) {
    const responseBody = await response.text();
    console.log("LOGIN FAILED", response.status, responseBody);
    setMessage(`Login failed with status ${response.status}: ${responseBody}`);
    setMessageColor('red');
    throw new Error(`Login failed | "LOGIN FAILED", ${response.status}, ${responseBody}, URL: ${url}`);
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log('Login successful!:', data);
  setMessage('Login successful!');
  setMessageColor('green');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Login error:', error);
  setMessage(`Login error: ${error.message}`);
  setMessageColor('red');
}

};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Tried setting in AndroidManifest.xml to set android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
Changing the local ip address to 10.0.2.2 instead of the 192.168.etc...
-Using my physical phone device to debug and


http://10.0.2.2:8080
That only works for the emulator contacting a server on the host machine.  For a physical device, you need the actual IP of the server, and your wifi network needs to be set up to allow traffic from an internal device to the server's IP and port.  That will likely require configuring your wifi router and will only work when they are on the same wifi network.  When you want to go to a real production build, you'll need to set up a real server with a public IP, DNS records for it, etc.

Thank you for clarifying for me. So, in order for me to get it connect locally through my local network thorugh wifi I will need to:
-Use the actual IP of the server. Is this the PC that I am using to run my docker keycloak service instance?
-Set up wifi network to allow traffic from internal device to the server's IP port. Is this something that can be configured through USB tethering in Network Connections in control panel? Or I would have to into my router settings. My device and PC running the docker instance is on the same local network/wifi network
